# Why does gevent execute this unjoined greenlet?

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent, greenlets

Code:

```
import gevent
import time

def func(a, t):
  time.sleep(t)
  print "got here", a

gevent.spawn(func, 'a', 4)
gevent.spawn(func, 'b', 0).join()
time.sleep(3)
print "exit"
```

Output:

```
got here a
got here b
exit
```

Expectation:

I never join on the first greenlet, so I expect that it will never execute; or, given the long sleep(), it should complete after the second greenlet.

Context:

I would like to be able to fire off a "throwaway" greenlet that populates a cache which I never join on and I never want to block to wait for the result of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `time.sleep()` isn't gevent-aware, so when `join()` is called, the execution flow will be:

1. `gevent.spawn(a)` — pushes a "spawn a" operation onto the event queue
2. `gevent.spawn(b)` — pushes a "spawn b" operation onto the event queue
3. `.join()` — causes the main thread to yield and next event in the event queue is executed (in this case, `a`)
4. `a` executes `time.sleep(4)`, blocking the entire process for 4 seconds (but thread `a` doesn't yield because `time.sleep()` isn't gevent-aware)
5. `a` terminates and the next event in the event queue is executed (in this case, `b`)
6. `b` executes and terminates, and the next event on the queue is executed (in this case, jumping back into the main thread, causing the `.join()` to return)

Use either [gevent.monkey](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html) or `gevent.sleep()` to see this perform as you'd expect.

Comment: Why does it execute at all if I never join on it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify a bit what's going on behind the scenes… Does that help?

Comment: so gevent has a global event queue, and calling join() on a single greenlet actually starts everything in the queue?

Comment: Uuhh… Sort of, yes! Calling join pushes an event onto the end of the queue which is "resume once <thread> has completed", then yields (nb: there may be some optimizations there if the thread has already completed… but that's the general idea).

Comment: In general, blocking operations in gevent are handled by pushing an event onto the queue and then yielding. At least, that's a reasonable mental model.